# Where to mount RING doorbell?

Tags: doorbell

I had a RING doorbell at our last house mounted on the wood siding. At our new house, there is a doorbell in a narrow channel with brick on one side and a metal door with plastic trim on the other.

As you can see, the RING barely fits.

We are renting, so I'm a little reluctant to hammer drill the landlord's brick wall.

Is there any creative way to mount this thing? If I can't use the old doorbell's wiring, that's OK since the RING is rechargeable.

[image]

Comment: If you never prop your storm door open why not mount it on the door? Double sided tape.

Comment: "Barely fits" seems good enough to me! If the storm door clears the Ring, go for it! If it doesn't quite clear it, use some double-sided tape to attach it to the brick. Expect that it may disappear if someone realizes how it's attached and decides to "borrow" it. Of course, you should have pictures of them if they do, right?

Comment: Ring makes a spacer block for these units to change the aim of the camera.

Comment: Let’s see you rent and because something you want to install is tight you are even thinking about changing the brick work in any way sounds like a good way to to loose a security deposit.

Comment: Not ideal, but you could drill the mortar and patch it pretty easily on departure.

Comment: @Kris - I found a few of these online, but how did you see these being used in this scenario?

Comment: It wil help you aim the camera upward or to the left or right without taking up any more space